# How to add spaces between items in TOC

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents

The mini-document

```
\documentclass[12pt,openany,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\titlecontents{part}[3pc]{\addvspace{3pc}\filcenter}
{\sffamily\bfseries PART \thecontentslabel\\*[.2pc]\large}
{\sffamily\bfseries\large}{}[\addvspace{.5pc}]


\title{Title}
\date{}
\author{pythonee}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Front One}
\lipsum[1]

\mainmatter
\part{Introduction}
\chapter{history}
\lipsum

\backmatter
\chapter{Back One}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

The Toc output look like:
[image: output]

Now I want to make the space between `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` equals to `\frontmatter and`\mainmatter` in Toc.

By the way. Why the **PART** doesn't display in TOC. I have customized it with `titletoc`.

[image: vertical spaces between chapter should be compact]

Comment: I don't understand your first request; can you please explain in more detail what you want to achieve?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina In simple terms, just for this case. I want to add spaces between **1 history** and **Back One**. I want to make it equals to the space between **Front one** and **"I Introduction"**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the second issue, you need to use the `newparttoc`package option for `titlesec` and `\titleformat` for `\part` to make `\titlecontents{part}...` behave as expected (I find this somehow surprising; using `scrbook` instead of `book` this is not necessary, so I don't know if this was intentional by design).

For the spacing issue, you can redefine `\backmatter` as implemented in `book.cls` to add the desired vertical space.

Now that an additional request has been made in a comment to this answer, you can use `\titlecontents` to format the chapter entries.

Here's a complete example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,openany,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[newparttoc]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\part}[display]
  {\centering\Huge\bfseries}{\partname~\thepart}
  {1em}{\normalfont\bfseries}

\titlecontents{part}[3pc]{\addvspace{3pc}\filcenter}
  {\sffamily\bfseries\MakeUppercase{\partname}~\thecontentslabel\\*[.2pc]\large}
  {\sffamily\bfseries\large}{}[\addvspace{3pc}]

\titlecontents{chapter}[0em]{}
  {\bfseries\chaptername~\thecontentslabel\hspace{1em}}
  {\bfseries}
  {\hfill\bfseries\contentspage}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\backmatter{%
  \if@openright
    \cleardoublepage
  \else
    \clearpage
  \fi
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{3pc}}
  \@mainmatterfalse}
\makeatother

\title{Title}
\date{}
\author{pythonee}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Front One}
\lipsum[1]

\mainmatter
\part{Introduction}
\chapter{history}
\lipsum
\chapter{Some more history}
\lipsum

\backmatter
\chapter{Back One}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, But if I can do this in my own style file, I think that would be better idea. I don't want to add toc line one by one. And How can I make **1 history** to **chapter 1 history**.

Comment: @pythonee please see my updated answer.

Comment: Yes, I want to add the vertical spacing. And your output is really what I want. But I think if I can remove **\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{3pc}}
**. And add vertical spacing between `\mainmatter` and `\backmatter` on my style file. That will be better.

Comment: @pythonee: answer updated. Is it something like that what you want?

Comment: Misunderstanded. I have updated my question. The chapters in one part should be compact.

Comment: @pythonee: please see my new updated answer. I think we are getting closer ;-)